# My wp-admin and is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with my wp-admin as it is saying that:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output. For help, please see this documentation or try the support forums

I have tried all possible ways to fix it but I am unable to fix this problem so I need your help . The ways I tried are:

1. Changing the theme into default.
2. Deactivating the plugins.
3. Re-configuring the WP-Config.php file.
4. Did Wp-debug value ,  true.
5. Had given a closing tag in function.php file as well.

Friends my project is running well in localhost and in live the project is running but its backend is not working

Comment: Er... Did you enable cookies in your browser? Try with another browser?

Comment: Having the same problem my friend.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the image? Use imgur.com.

Comment: Check functions.php remove php end tag if there is or if you have not closed a curly bracket close it.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu How is this related to cookies?

Comment: @PraveenKumar let him try it then I will post an answer .

Comment: Sir I did this too 
As I am new to wordpress I am doing the best possible way to resolve the problem .
As I have seen in google many clients are facing the same kind of problem in wordpress.

Comment: @Chetan Do not need to use sir, at least for me, is there any space before `<?php` tag on your page ?

Comment: @Prafulla Kumar Sahu     
No space is not there before <?php in my function.php file.

Comment: If disabling plugins is not enough (changeing the theme won't matter, it's not used in  the backend) you should restore all files to it's original states. Meaning remove all from the webspace, reupload WordPress, recreate the wp-config.php file.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider Sir could You please explain in details how I  can resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible situations that are capable of creating this error:

1. UTF-8 => are your files UTF-8? no BOM (have you opened live files with Notepad ++?), [more info about this problem](http://emlev.com/blog/how-to-fix-error-cookies-are-blocked-due-to-unexpected-output/)
2. [Remove all plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F), try again to log in (to make sure there is not a plugin creating the "headers already sent by ...)
3. The same goes for Themes
4. remove the closing `?>`in functions.php

Comment: Yes I did that I have reuploaded my project its working fine but the admin is not opening . Having same problem vth backend

Answer (score 0):

In `functions.php`, please remove the `?>` from end if it exists.

Comment: Yes I did that . But I m unable to understand that what is the role of cookies in my wp-login.php . Why is it not allowing me to login.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question after long struggle.
 1. I put a function in wp-config.php file 
     function : ob_start(); just above my WP-DEBUG function.
 2. I changed my hosting service as there was some kind of virus in the server which was automatically changing the file permission of index.php and .htaccess files.

Finally my site is live and I am very happy for that and Thank You everyone who helped me in solving my problem.

Best Regards,
Chetan

Answer (score -3):

To fix the bug:

1. Open file blog/wp-admin/includes/screen.php in your favorite text
   editor.
2. On line 706 find the following PHP statement: `<?php echo
   self::$this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
3. Replace it with the statement: `<?php echo $this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
4. Save your changes.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: ? whats the change? `_help_sidebar; ?>` and `_help_sidebar; ?>`

Comment: However, never change the WP core files.

Comment: The change was not visible since the code wasn't in a code block and part of it got eaten by the markup. Fixed now.

Comment: In my screen.php file no such php statement exists.

Comment: Well, the difference between Self::$this was working in older version. but after update, my dashboard or login pages was blank. 

I searched on some forum and found this solution and it works for me. 
So I shared here too.